# MYSQL Deduplicate and remove the duplicate row with least data

Tags: mysql

I am working on a MYSQL database which has the following three columns: emails, name, surname.

What I need to do is deduplicate the emails where I know I can use a function such as this one (this query just to sort not delete):

```
select distinct emails, name, surname from emails;
```

or

```
select emails, name, surname from emails group by emails having count(*) >= 2;
```

However I also need to make sure that when there a duplicate email address is found that the one kept is the one that has a name and/or surname value.

For example:

|id | emails              | name      | surname      |
|1 | bob@bob.com  | bob    | paulson   |
|2 | bob@bob.com  |           |                 |

In this case I would like to keep the first result and delete the second.

I have been looking into using 'case' or 'if' statements but am not experienced with using those. I tried expanding the above functions with those statements but to no avail.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

PS: The first column in the table is an auto-incremented id value, in case that helps

UPDATE 1: So far @Bohemian answer below is working great but fails in one case where there is a duplicate emails address where in one row it has a name but no surname and in the next row it has no name but has a surname. It will keep both records. All that needs to be edited is so that one of these two records gets deleted, no matter which.

UPDATE 2: @Bohemian's answer is great, but after more testing I've found that it has a fundamental flaw in that it works only when there is a duplicate email row where the name and surname fields have data (like the first entry in the table above). If there are duplicates of an email but none of the rows have both the name and surname fields filled in then all those rows will be ignored and not deduplicated.

The last step for this query would be to work out how to delete the duplicates that don't meet the current necessary conditions. If one row has just name and the other just surname, it really doesn't matter which gets deleted as the email is the important thing to keep.

Comment: what need to do when one row having name and next having surname?

Comment: Is this something you are going to do regularly or is it just a one-time fix?

Comment: In that case I would think that the best solution would be to concatenate the two, although I assume that this can complicate matters a whole lot.

Comment: This is a one time thing, but will be used maybe once a month to clear the db as it gets updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this DELETE query, which is generic and can be easily adapted to support more fields:

```
DELETE tablename.*
FROM
  tablename LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) min_id
    FROM
      tablename t INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
          emails, MAX((name IS NOT NULL) + (surname IS NOT NULL)) max_non_nulls
        FROM
          tablename
        GROUP BY
          emails) m
      ON t.emails=m.emails
         AND ((t.name IS NOT NULL) + (t.surname IS NOT NULL))=m.max_non_nulls
    GROUP BY
      t.emails) ids
  ON tablename.id=ids.min_id
WHERE
  ids.min_id IS NULL
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d359/1).

This query returns the maximum number of non null fields, for every email:

```
SELECT
  emails,
  MAX((name IS NOT NULL) + (surname IS NOT NULL)) max_non_nulls
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  emails
```

I'm then joining this query with tablename, to get the minimum ID for every email that has the maximum number of non null fields:

```
SELECT MIN(id) min_id
FROM
  tablename t INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      emails, MAX((name IS NOT NULL) + (surname IS NOT NULL)) max_non_nulls
    FROM
      tablename
    GROUP BY
      emails) m
  ON t.emails=m.emails
     AND ((t.name IS NOT NULL) + (t.surname IS NOT NULL))=m.max_non_nulls
GROUP BY
  t.emails
```

and then I'm deleting all rows that have an ID that is not returned by this query.

Comment: thank you so much for that, the query works perfectly. Also appreciate the explanation of the steps you've taken, it helps a lot. Any way I can donate you a beer?

Answer (score 4):

This is easy with mysql's [multiple-table delete syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

```
delete b
from mytable a
join mytable b
  on a.email = b.email
  and a.id != b.id
where a.name is not null
and a.surname is not null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bohemian that query works well. The only case where it does not work is when a duplicate email in one row has a name and no surname and the other has no name but does have a username. In this case both are kept. In such a case it is not really important which is kept, but one must go.

Comment: Yeah, there's a slight logical error there - but it's easily fixed ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry would you care to share the fix you have in mind?

Comment: I've also just noticed that when there is a duplicate and neither row has a name or surname they are also both kept.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete record with duplicate email id**

```
delete 
    from duplicate_email where id in(
        select id from (
            select id, email from duplicate_email group by email having count(id) > 1) as id
    )
```

but there is one problem you can delete those record which have only one duplicate email i.e two same email but if there are three or more, you can repeat this query until you get zero record deleted