# Need some help to clean duplicates in MySQL table which didn't have constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, query-optimization

I've inherited some MySQL table that was designed without correct constraint so it gets filled with some duplicate rows which I need to remove. The problem that across duplicate rows data isn't usually consistent, see example below:

| id | request_id | guid_id | details | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | fh82EN | help me | 1 |
| 2 | 11 | fh82EN |  |  |
| 3 | 12 | fh82EN | assistance required | 1 |
| 4 | 12 | fh82EN | assistance required | 1 |
| 5 | 13 | fh82EN |  |  |
| 6 | 13 | fh82EN | assist me. | 1 |
| 7 | 13 | fh82EN |  |  |
| 8 | 14 | fh82EN |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Records with id: 1,2,8 perfectly fine. For duplicate records with id 3, 4 I have designed the query below which works fine and removes all duplicates without an issue:

```
DELETE IR.*
FROM platform.temp IR
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT maxId AS id FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) as maxId, request_id, guid_id
        FROM platform.temp
        GROUP BY request_id, guid_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS T
);
```

The problem is records with id 5,6,7. You can see that the same record by (guid_id and request_id) is not consistent. So, my previous query will delete records with content too because of `MAX(id)`. I have designed a query that fixes these records, but we are talking about a huge database and this query is painfully slow:

```
UPDATE platform.temp AS DEST_T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT request_id, guid_id, details, flag FROM platform.temp WHERE details IS NOT NULL AND details != ''
) AS SOURCE_T
SET DEST_T.details = SOURCE_T.details, DEST_T.flag = SOURCE_T.flag
    WHERE DEST_T.guid_id = SOURCE_T.guid_id AND DEST_T.request_id = SOURCE_T.request_id;
```

How can I change my delete query that it will order my subgroup by field `details` and will select not `MAX(id)` but first id, so I will be sure that last row in subgroup will always be populated with value and will left?

**MySQL version**: 5.6.40-log

**UPDATE1**:
The desired outcome after cleaning the table should be as follow:

| id | request_id | guid_id | details | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | fh82EN | help me | 1 |
| 2 | 11 | fh82EN |  |  |
| 3 | 12 | fh82EN | assistance required | 1 |
| 6 | 13 | fh82EN | assist me. | 1 |
| 8 | 14 | fh82EN |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Please add what the end result should be on the sample data as it would be easier to spot the pattern required.

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: @Stu, `5.6.40-log` thank you!

Comment: Possible help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989882/mysql-deduplicate-and-remove-the-duplicate-row-with-least-data  And, your MySql version is *really* old. Chasing performance problems on it is a waste of time because newer versions are so much faster. Upgrade.

Comment: are the details identical for all request_id  guid_id combinations?

Comment: That's a shame, it's extremely trivial to solve using `row_number()` which you don't have.

Comment: @nbk, no! Will fix the question.

Comment: Just in case it helps you, the solution using `window_functions` (needs v8) is here [MySql8 working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3879730c2543add0d5f12d69a0a6cf5d)

Comment: it is quite unclear what you want to happen, i would add a row_number and take the first as you seem to want only 1 result but when `13  fh82EN` had `help me` and ` assist me` which one to choose?

Comment: @nbk, I need that every pair `request_id` and `guid_id` will be present only once. And if few such pairs exist some with values, some without, the one with value will be kept.

Comment: @Anatoly that didn't answer my question what if there are two **different** texts for the **same** guid and request_id

Comment: @nbk, It shouldn't happen. Anyway, it's such a rare case that we can neglect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join of the table:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.request_id = t1.request_id AND t2.guid_id = t1.guid_id
WHERE (t2.id < t1.id AND COALESCE(t1.details, '') = '')
      OR
      (t2.id > t1.id AND COALESCE(t2.details, '') <> '');
```

This will keep 1 row for each `request_id` and `guid_id` combination, not necessarily the one with the min `id`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e32d925477cc48cef14c9a30deedd13a).

Another way to do it, with conditional aggregation:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT request_id, guid_id,
         MIN(id) min_id,
         MIN(CASE WHEN COALESCE(details, '') <> '' THEN id END) min_id_not_null
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY request_id, guid_id
) t2 ON t2.request_id = t1.request_id AND t2.guid_id = t1.guid_id
WHERE t1.id <> COALESCE(t2.min_id_not_null, t2.min_id);
```

This will keep the row with the min `id` under your conditions, but maybe its performance would not be that good compared to the 1st query.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=867c76b16f2ce184a606a1212cd125b3).

Comment: OP want id 3 in the result while your result is giving id as 4. This needs to be fixed.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I already mention this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to emulate the ROW_NUMBER ad then perform the delete operation.

```
DELETE FROM test
 WHERE id NOT IN (select id
                    from (SELECT id, 
                                 @row_number := CASE WHEN @last_request_id <> x.request_id + x.guid_id
                                                          THEN 1 ELSE @row_number + 1 END AS row_num,
                                 @last_request_id := x.request_id + x.guid_id
                            FROM test x
                           CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @last_request_id := null, @last_guid_id := null) y
                           ORDER BY request_id, guid_id, details DESC) temp
                   where row_num = 1);
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3f3cfe9df77f572f21ade9299d5a550c)

Comment: I get the following error: `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'T1' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comments i would use it with row_numbers, which in mysql 8 would look much more nicer

> ```
> CREATE TABLE temp
>     (`id` varchar(4), `request_id` varchar(12), `guid_id` varchar(9), `details` varchar(21), `flag` varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO temp
>     (`id`, `request_id`, `guid_id`, `details`, `flag`)
> VALUES
>  
>     ('1', '10', 'fh82EN', 'help me', '1'),
>     ('2', '11', 'fh82EN', NULL, NULL),
>     ('3', '12', 'fh82EN', 'assistance required', '1'),
>     ('4', '12', 'fh82EN', 'assistance required', '1'),
>     ('5', '13', 'fh82EN', NULL, NULL),
>     ('6', '13', 'fh82EN', 'assistance required', '1'),
>     ('7', '13', 'fh82EN', NULL, NULL),
>     ('8', '14', 'fh82EN', NULL, NULL)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> DELETE t1
> FROM temp t1 INNER JOIN 
> (SELECT `id`
> , IF(@request = `request_id` AND @guid = guid_id, @rn:= @rn+1,@rn := 1) rn
> ,@request := `request_id` as request_id
> ,@guid := guid_id as guid_id
> fROM temp,(SELECT @request := 0, @guid := '',@rn := 0) t1
> ORDER BY  `guid_id`,`request_id`,`details` DESC, id) t2 ON 
> t1.`id` = t2.`id` AND rn > 1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM temp
> ```
>
> ```
> id | request_id | guid_id | details             | flag
> :- | :--------- | :------ | :------------------ | :---
> 1  | 10         | fh82EN  | help me             | 1   
> 2  | 11         | fh82EN  | null                | null
> 3  | 12         | fh82EN  | assistance required | 1   
> 6  | 13         | fh82EN  | assistance required | 1   
> 8  | 14         | fh82EN  | null                | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b9d87a93bef384886ac4d86940776d68)*